# android: tablerow mixed with columns and multiline text

Tags: android, view, tablelayout, tablerow

I am trying to have a tablelayout contains several tablerows. One of the rows contains 4 buttons, while the second row contains a very long text. However, the width of the button stretches with the text in the second row. Is there anyway to prevent this?

[image]
 [image]

http://img684.imageshack.us/i/tableview1.jpg/

http://img521.imageshack.us/i/tableview2.jpg/

Here is my xml file: (somehow this website is not friendly to xml file)

```
AbsoluteLayout
android:id="@+id/widget0"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>

TableLayout
android:id="@+id/widget28"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_x="0px"
android:layout_y="10px"
>

TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget29"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

Button
android:id="@+id/widget30"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
>
</Button>

Button
android:id="@+id/widget31"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
>
</Button>

Button
android:id="@+id/widget32"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
>
</Button>

Button
android:id="@+id/widget33"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
>
</Button>
</TableRow>

TableRow
android:id="@+id/widget35"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
>

TextView
android:id="@+id/widget40"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView"
>
</TextView>
</TableRow>

</TableLayout>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

Comment: Also tried to set the attributes in code, didn't work. Is it a bug by android?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using android:layout_span="4" for TextView

Replace 4 by whatever be the number of columns(buttons) in first row is..

Also, you can leave out android:layout_width and layout_height parameters from the Tablerow

Comment: It didn't work out. The text strentched ouside the screen, the first button is still that big.

I am starting to wondering if it is a bug of android?

Comment: It works for me, here is the working XML for 2nd row from my side (probably you put layout_span attribute at wrong place):
<TableRow android:id="@+id/widget35" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" >
<TextView android:id="@+id/widget40" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_span="4"  android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" /> </TableRow>

Also, you can easily omit:
 layout_width="wrap_content" layout_height="wrap_content"
from the Button and other tablerow tags.

Comment: Also, why are you using an AbsoluteLayout, i would not recommend using it unless its absolute necessity.

Comment: Thanks...it is still not working for me though. I have give up and used a separate Linearlayout for these buttons.